"package" compatibility solver with verion ranges
I am looking for how to solve the package compatibility problem. I have found some relevant research and libraries. But some of them are older. I am wondering if there is any more recent research and development.
The most recent overview of the field is [2011.07851] Dependency Solving Is Still Hard, but We Are Getting Better at It. This is from 2020.
